# Are theses two the same

Tags: math

The formula for a sensor I'm using is:

```
%RH  = (125 * rhData / 65536) - 6
```

and the routine I've seen is:

```
*rhData = ( (uint32_t) readData[0] << 8 ) + ( readData[1] & 0xfc );
*rhData = ( ( ( *rhData ) * 15625L ) >> 13 ) - 6000;
```

I cant see that the two are the same, can someone explain how it works?

Yours Simon M.

Comment: What programming language is the code in? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a fixed point format with scale 1000. Then the integer representing the result is

```
RH*1000 = 5^3 * rhData / 2^16 * 2^3*5^3
        = 5^6 * rhData / 2^13
        = (15625 * rhData) >> 13
```

which is exactly what is used in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

It was a brain fade day! 
Multiply 125 * 1000, then divide by 2 to find the lowest integer. (15625)

What threw me is 125^2 = 15625

Thanks

Yours Simon M.